# The feature name "siteContext" does not exist in the state, therefore createFeatureSelector cannot access it

Tags: angular, ngrx, spartacus-storefront

Can the following warning be fixed/avoided?

```
store.js:607 The feature name "siteContext" does not exist in the state, 
therefore createFeatureSelector cannot access it.  Be sure it is 
imported in a loaded module using StoreModule.forRoot('siteContext', 
...) or StoreModule.forFeature('siteContext', ...).  If the default 
state is intended to be undefined, as is the case with router state, 
this development-only warning message can be ignored.
```

I saw that the **createFeatureSelector(featureName)** store function is called multiple times. The state is not initialized for the first call with 'siteContext' as a featureName so the warning message is displayed to the console (only in dev mode).

I'm using version 1.2.1 of *spartacus/core* and *spartacus/storefront*

Comment: 1. Do you consume the state of the site context (language, currency or baseSite) in the constructor of any service? If yes, can you try consuming it later (i.e. in some method invoked later)?
2. Did you customize any service of Spartacus related to the site context?

Comment: Thank you for your help! 1. We do consume LanguageService and CurrencyService in the constructors of two services and the CurrencyService also in the constructor of a component. We have a custom date service, widely used across the app, that injects the LanguageService in its constructor and subscribes to the getActive() Observable to get the locale. I will investigate to see if it's possible to postpone the services initialization. 2. I did not find any customization of a Spartacus site context related service.

Comment: For testing I completely removed LanguageService and Currency Service from all the services/components that use them in their constructors but I still see the warning. Also, maybe it helps: in the Redux inspector I can see that the siteContext state gets initialized after @ngrx/store/init action in which the uninitialized siteContext objects are present (with default null values).